# CSS issue with chrome running on OSX

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code :

```
<div class="submit"><input type="button" name="getResult" value="Get Comments" class="sbutton" /></div>
```

and the CSS is :

```
#sForm .submit {
float:left;
width:100%;
margin-top:10px;
}

#sForm .sbutton {
width:100%;
height:50px;
font-size:70px;
padding-left:10px;
}
```

assume the html is wrapper around : `<div id="sForm"></div>`

the entire page works except the button `getResult` . it doesnt take any of the CSS attributes except `width:100%`. but the same page loads fine on firefox.

Comment: Do you have a live example? Also re-make your markup to include the wrapper, instead of appending it.

Comment: no I have it installed on my localhost, if it helps I can give you a screenshot!! (eventhough I know it doesnt!! )

Comment: You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ for making a live example to make everyone happy.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TYLe6/ there it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put your example in a jsfiddle and was able to replicate the issue. It looks like you need the `-webkit-appearance:button;` in your button selector:

http://jsfiddle.net/aj2AX/

Comment: I am sorry but I dont follow, can you explain your answer or put the code here?

Comment: He is right just add this line -webkit-appearance:button;  inside the #sForm .sbutton { block

Comment: The -webkit-appearance:button tells it to work and look like a more traditional button, rather than using the OS X styles, which i believe uses fixed image sizes.